# Phonon video player getting stuck on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, python

I am trying to play video using Python Phonon player in my raspberry pi2, it is getting stuck after 2 to 3 seconds at a resolution of video 720 X 480. But the video is smoothly playing the other resolutions 160x200, 320x200, 320x240, 640x200, 640x480. Actual resolution of video is 720 x 480. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        src = Phonon.MediaSource(path + "video1.mp4")
        self.media.setCurrentSource(src)
        self.media.play()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):        
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))

        MainWindow.resize(scr_w, scr_h)
        MainWindow.move(0,-28)

        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))

        self.media = Phonon.MediaObject(MainWindow)
        self.video_widget = Phonon.VideoWidget(self.centralwidget)
        Phonon.createPath(self.media, self.video_widget)  
        self.audio_out = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.VideoCategory)
        Phonon.createPath(self.media, self.audio_out)

        self.video_widget.setGeometry(0, 0, 720, 480)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that video size is the problem. It seems that Phonon makes use of only `CPU` to process mp4 videos and shows it on screen and CPU may not be able to cope up to deliver real time performance for higher resolution videos and hence it is stuck.

You can have a look at `Omxplayer` or something similar that makes use of RPi GPU which can render 1080p videos without any glitch using RPi GPU, and if you could incorporate it in your program.

Also, may I know which SD card class you're using currently ? It would be worth to try a class 10 or higher for better IO performance to check the performance. I'm not sure if it affects the performance or not. But worth a try.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think SD card speed will affect this.  The [worst benchmarks here](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards#External_Benchmarks) are at least 4-5 MB/s read speed, which is plenty for any kind of video.   Most of them are at least double that, and the card class does not seem a perfect predictor (there are class 10 cards with bottom-of-the-pile benchmarks).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am already using class 10 SD card, I need to put video in a part of a window, so i have to use phonon player. Is it possible to place Omxplayer to a part of a window?

Comment: @ArunPrakashT Do you mean Windows 10 IoT core ? I don't know much about it.

Comment: @dastaan No, I am using RPi2 and Qwidget to design main window and place phonon media player as an object in the part of the main window.

Comment: @ArunPrakashT Aah, yes. But I don't know any of solution that would work out of the box but this seems to be a point to start.https://github.com/carlonluca/pi